# Weak linking? External class? Is that possible

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, weak-references, weak-linking, external-dependencies

I'm straggling with that issue couple of days.

Issue is that we build the SDK while using cocoa pods internally. The result is going to be a closed source fat library with public headers. One of the pods is AFNetworking. IMO we shouldn't include AFNetworking (and other pods) into out library, because of the following reasons:

- we don't want to do have collisions/duplicated symbols if SDK user also adds it's own AFNetworking
- we don't want to be forced to keep updating our framework because of AFNetworking update (i.g. due to security enhancements), and this is multiplied by each other pod we use

So what we want to do is to deliver a closed source SDK with instructions that user needs to deliver it's own copy of AFNetworking (possibly with the recommended version in notes). Is that possible?

Comment: As long as AFNetworking is available, the linker step should work in apps. Did you figure out what to do eventually?